Why my Auth0 : password_change_required is not triggered?
We use Auth0 for our authentication system, we couldn't connect yesterday and we don't know why but as soon as we reset our password it works.
Someone see that our password expired after 180 days, so we addpassword_change_required to our code
languageDictionary: {
    error: {
        login: {
            "lock.invalid_email_password": "Please check your email and password.",
             password_change_required:'Please reset your password.'
        }
    },

So it should trigger that the password need to change because it is expired.
This is there documentation.
Someone tell me today that it's not triggered and the page reload without showing the message "please reset your password"
In case someone wants to know the front is in javascript for this part and in C# for the entire project.
--------------------- UPDATE ---------------------
I add this to my code :
lock.on('authorization_error', function (err) {
    if (err.error === 'password_change_required' || err.error_description.includes('password_change_required')) {
        alert('Please reset your password.');
    } else {
        //console.error('Error :', err);
    }
});

But it doesn't trigger the alert or the message.

Looks like you are only configuring translation with what you have shown us so far, not sure why you'd expect this to affect the functionality?

@C3roe oh it's just translation, I thought it will trigger also the fact that the user password is expired. Then how can I trigger it ?

I couldn't even tell you whether that exists as a feature in the first place, to have it automatically redirect to the password change page. Guess you'll need to check the Auth0 documentation.
